# Port disconnection on Netgear GSM7328Sv2

Tags: port, netgear

I have a GSM7328Sv2 cascaded with some GS724TS (unstacked) and two tagged VLANs.

The switch works fine, but sometimes it disables itself a cascaded port (almost always the same port), without apparent reason.

When this happens :

- The connection is interrupted
- All other ports continue to operate normally
- LED on the switch is off
- Nothing obvious in logs
- IMPORTANT: when I go *Switching> Ports*, I see the port with the *Admin Mode* column blank, while all other ports are *Enable*
- When I force *Admin Mode* to *Enable*, the connection restart normally in a few seconds.

I already changed the cable.

Does anyone have an idea of the cause (a faulty switch, security reasons, storm something?)
Does anyone have an idea how to prevent it happening again ?

Currently, the port shutdown almost 1x per day...

Comment: It might be worth checking that the switch's firmware is up-to-date.

Comment: The last time i have updated the firmware, the switch was unable to boot again.

Answer (score 0):

In cisco land, there is a feature (`port-security`) which can be configured to disable a port if it sees more than some arbitrary number of MAC addresses, in order to prevent the connection of unauthorized equipment.  I wonder if something like this is configurable on your device.

Failing that, it could be faulty hardware on either end, or a bug in the switch's firmware.  Because updating it renders it unbootable, there is probably some faulty hardware there.